# Global hotkey to set textbox value

Tags: c#, clipboard, sendkeys

Currently I have global hot keys setup to paste the contents of a text box into the current active form (browser). These work perfectly fine (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> - <kbd>9</kbd>), however I'm trying to do a reverse of that by setting the text box value from an external value. Initially I thought it would be easy, since they're global hotkeys I'd just highlight what I want and then press the hotkey (<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> - <kbd>9</kbd>) and it would SendKeys.Send("^c"), and then set the TextBox.Text = Clipboard.GetText(), however this doesn't behave as expected and returns seemingly random values from in my code/past clipboard entries.

I had a look around and found various things which also didn't help. It's important to note that I'll always be calling this global hotkey from the current active window, so I don't need to find/set the active window, meerly just send a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> command and have it reliably execute it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
RegisterHotKey(Handle, 12, 0x0001, (int) Keys.D1);

case (12):
if (x.Text == "" || x.Text == @"YYYYYY")
{
    //Window is in Focus and the text is already highlighted
    SendKeys.SendWait("^c");
    x.Text = Clipboard.GetText();                          
}
return;
```

Bonus points, can I expand the clipboard class to return the count of the selection before doing anything?

Edit:

My attempt at Sending WM_COPY:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

case (12):
if (x.Text == "" || x.Text == @"YYYYYY")
{
    //Window is in Focus and the text is already highlighted
    SendMessage(m.HWnd, 0x0301, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0);
    x.Text = Clipboard.GetText();                          
}
return;
```

Comment: Tried sending `WM_COPY`?

Comment: @BenVoigt I also tried that, I'll edit in my code I used.